# How to get the value of selected button in twitter bootstrap button group

Tags: javascript, radio-button, twitter-bootstrap, buttongroup

If I haev a radio button group in bootstrap like the following :

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
        <button class="btn">1</button>
        <button class="btn">2</button>
        <button class="btn">3</button>
        <button class="btn">4</button>
</div>
```

How can I `get`/ `set` the selected value ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var num = null;
var ele = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-group > button.btn");
for(var i=0; i<ele.length; i++){
    ele[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        num = +this.innerHTML;
        alert("Value is " + num);
    });
}
```

Or jQuery:

```
var num = null;
$(".btn-group > button.btn").on("click", function(){
    num = +this.innerHTML;
    alert("Value is " + num);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to set the value the group

Comment: @Adham - `this.innerHTML = value`

Answer (score 16):

To set the active element, add the class `active` to whichever button you want selected (and deselect the rest).

```
$('.btn-group > .btn').removeClass('active')    // Remove any existing active classes
$('.btn-group > .btn').eq(0).addClass('active') // Add the class to the nth element
```

To get the html/text content of the currently active button, try something like this:

```
$('.btn-group > .btn.active').html()
```

Comment: It would actually require setting active on one and unsetting active on all others. Not a very nice interface IMO.

Comment: This is the final solution I came up with to get the selected element , `$('.btn-group > .btn.active input')[0]`

Answer (score 15):

Here is one more solution

```
 alert($('.btn-group > .btn.active').text());
```